# Auto-fill form with link to external page

Tags: php, html, forms, hyperlink

I am looking for a way for a text field and submission button to take me to a new site, fill out a text input field and hit enter. The page I want to link to is [Googles speed test](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights). I know I can link to spped test results as well like this:
`https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights#url=http_3A_2F_2FYOURDOMAINHERE&mobile=false` 
but how can I have a customer fill out a "test my page" field on my site, hit submit, and it create a link to:
 `https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights#url=http_3A_2F_2FYOURDOMAINHERE&mobile=false`
with their field submission in the "YOURDOMAINHERE" area of the link. This seems linke not a huge task but i cannot wrap my head around it, php, javascript??? not sure. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something similar to this, although if Google catches you according to their TOC they *could* lock or ban your account:

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST['url'])){
    $url = preg_replace('!http[s]://!','',strip_tags($_POST['url']));
    $url = preg_replace('![%]!','_',urlencode($url));
    $newlink = "https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights#url=$url&mobile=false";

    $page = '<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>';

    $page .= '<script type="text/javascript">
    function replaceDoc()
  {
  window.location.replace("'.$newlink.'")
  }
    </script>';


$page .= '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Page for testing</title>
</head>
<body onload="replaceDoc()">

    <a href="'.$newlink.'">Test your page.</a>

</body>
</html>
    ';
} else {
 $page = '<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Page Checker</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post">
Enter your URL:<br />
<input name="url" type="text" style="width:50em;" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Check your page" />
</form>
</body>
</html>';

}

echo $page;
?>
```

Be careful directly injecting headers:

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST['url'])){
    $url = preg_replace('!http[s]://!','',strip_tags($_POST['url']));
    $url = preg_replace('![%]!','_',urlencode($url));
    $newlink = "https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights#url=$url&mobile=false";

    header("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    header("Referer: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights");
    header("Location: $newlink");

} else {
 $page = '<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Page Checker</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post">
Enter your URL:<br />
<input name="url" type="text" style="width:50em;" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Check your page" />
</form>
</body>
</html>';

}

echo $page;
?>
```

Comment: Im obviously weary about doing something that might get me banned by google. How does sending people to their search results page in a new window but auto populating their field violate their TOC . They are getting way out of hand.

Comment: "Don’t misuse our Services. For example, don’t interfere with our Services or try to access them using a method other than the interface and the instructions that we provide." from https://www.google.com/intl/en/policies/terms/

Comment: You're basically providing a new landing page and bypassing their existing interface that protects them (and checks) for valid URLs. They *could* blame you if someone uses your script for an XSS attack.

Comment: No need to delete the question though... it might help someone else who is considering doing the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

make a submit.php

have the form submit to that script with the "DOMAIN NAME"

your php should look something like this..

```
$domainName = $_POST["domainname"];
$redirectURL = "https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights#url=http_3A_2F_2F".$domainName."&mobile=false";
header('Location: $redirectURL');
```

That script should work havn't tested it but it'll give you an idea...

make sure you sanitize your inputs too... :) good luck

Answer (score 0):

Hows about a simple `str_replace`?  Something like:

```
<?php

$link = "https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights#url=http_3A_2F_2FYOURDOMAINHERE&mobile=false";
$replace = "YOURDOMAINHERE";

if(isset($_POST['myDomain'])){
  $newHeader = str_replace($replace, $_POST['myDomain'], $link);
  header("Location: ".$newHeader);
}

?>


<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">       
   <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>googleDomain</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="domain.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="myDomain" />
            <input type="submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I haven't tested this at all, but should be something pretty similar

Comment: Their site is checking referrers.